Path based routing with Nginx IC virtualServer not working
I have an Nginx ingress controller virtualServre manifest as
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: tea-vs
spec:
  host: apps.example.com
  routes:
  - path: /
    pathType: Prefix
    rewrite:
      path: /tea/
    route:
      path: /tea(.*)
      pathType: Prefix
      service:
        name: tea-svc
        port:
          number: 80

My app serves at /. When I type apps.example.com, it swagger UI loads and displays URL as apps.example.com/index.html
My requirement is:

if user enters apps.example.com/tea, the swagger UI should load even its serving at root.

My tea-svc should receive a request for apps.example.com but NOT apps.example.com/tea

Users still see the URL as apps.example.com/tea/index.html 

I prefer not to use Nginx Kind: Ingress 


My dotnet code is below, and I don't want to touch it as it's already working in PROD. I am doing this as part of the migration to Nginx ingress controller and wanted to migrate to path based routing from the host based which I feel will bring some flexibility
 app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

        app.UseRouting();

Struggling with this as I always get 404, when I attempt to do any path-based routing
Any help on this is highly appreciated

I am still looking for some suggestions on this. Thanks

Following the doc here:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: cafe
  namespace: cafe-ns
spec:
  host: cafe.example.com
  upstreams:
  - name: tea
    service: tea-svc
    port: 80
  routes:
  - path: /tea
    action:
      pass: tea
  - path: /coffee
    route: coffee-ns/coffee

apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServerRoute
metadata:
  name: coffee
  namespace: coffee-ns
spec:
  host: cafe.example.com
  upstreams:
  - name: latte
    service: latte-svc
    port: 80
  - name: espresso
    service: espresso-svc
    port: 80
  subroutes:
  - path: /coffee/latte
    action:
      pass: latte
  - path: /coffee/espresso
    action:
      pass: espresso

you should do something like above.
If your are trying rewrite:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=tea-svc rewrite=/;serviceName=coffee-svc rewrite=/beans/"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: tea-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /coffee/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: coffee-svc
            port:
              number: 80

You can use some example from here:
https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v3.6.1/examples
Let me know if it helps.

You are searching someone to do the work for you, got it. If you read , im using the examples to show for you that Kind Ingress have routes/rewrite.
Virtualserver doesn’t have. Adapt your manifest as the example above and will work.
